# GFG question implementation merge sorted linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/merge-two-sorted-linked-lists I tried writing the code for this question and wrote two possible answers. One worked and one did not. I need to know the reason. Why?
Implementation 1 -

```
class LinkedList
{
    //Function to merge two sorted linked list.
    Node sortedMerge(Node head1, Node head2) {
        Node beforeHead = new Node(-1);
        Node temp = beforeHead;
        temp = temp.next;
        while(head1!=null && head2!=null){
            if(head1.data<head2.data){
                temp = head1;
                head1 = head1.next;
            }else{
                temp = head2;
                head2 = head2.next;
            }
            //System.out.println(temp.data);
            //System.out.println(temp.next);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        
        while(head1!=null){
            temp = head1;
            head1 = head1.next;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        
        while(head2!=null){
            temp = head2;
            head2 = head2.next;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
       
        //System.out.println(beforeHead.next);
        return beforeHead.next;
   } 
}
```

There is some issue with the reference but I cannot find the reason.

Implementation 2 -

```
class LinkedList
{
    //Function to merge two sorted linked list.
    Node sortedMerge(Node head1, Node head2) {
        Node beforeHead = new Node(-1);
        Node temp = beforeHead;
        while(head1!=null && head2!=null){
            if(head1.data<head2.data){
                temp.next = head1;
                head1 = head1.next;
            }else{
                temp.next = head2;
                head2 = head2.next;
            }
            
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        
        while(head1!=null){
            temp.next = head1;
            head1 = head1.next;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        
        while(head2!=null){
            temp.next = head2;
            head2 = head2.next;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
       
        //System.out.println(beforeHead.next);
        return beforeHead.next;
   } 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first implementation, initially `temp= beforeHead->next`. which is `Null`.

I got the point that you are initialising `temp` variable with required values.
but where exactly those temp values are linked. For each iteration the `temp` values are changed without being linked with previous ones.

so finally all the nodes are created but none of them are linked.